# Running kile from terminal

Tags: 12.04, kile

I installed kile from offline installer and everytime I want to run it, I need to go to the install directory and then run it

```
cd /home/usrname/kile-install

./kile
```

is there anyway to add a command so that this process is automated?
i.e i want to type "kile" in the terminal and it should open kile.

**Edit:** tried modifying .bashrc file
added the following lines to .bashrc

- PATH=PATH$:/home/usrname/kile-install/bin
- PATH=PATH$:/home/usrname/R2009b/bin

The second one works but kile does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're installing the program for a single user only, there's no need to mess with system directories - you can configure everything in your home directory. No need to use `sudo` either.

Create a folder called `bin` in your home directory and create a symlink from your executable into that directory:

```
mkdir ~/bin
ln -s ~/kile-install/kile ~/bin
```

or, if `kile` needs to be started from a particular directory, create a small shell script and place it in `~/bin`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/usrname/kile-install
./kile
```

If you haven't had `~/bin` directory previously you'll need to log out and then log in back, but in the future it'll be added to your PATH automatically so everything you put there can be invoked without specifying the full path.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the binary file into /usr/local/bin with the following command:

```
sudo cp /home/username/kile-install/kile /usr/local/bin
```

/usr/local/bin is a folder where we usually put custom application binaries.
after copying, just re-open the terminal and you should be good to go.

Comment: Not working...This is what I get:

No protocol specified

No protocol specified
kile: cannot connect to X server :0

Comment: Oops! Missed the last sentence. Re-opened the terminal and it works like a charm! Thanks a lot!